# Unable to install "Runner" , failed to deploy app to app store using xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, store

I am using Flutter 2.10.3 , xcode 13.2.1 ,,,

When I want to Archive my app to deploy, the build is done successfully , but the pop-up window does not contain the option to deploy to app store. This is the result pop-up window:

[Archive result pop-up window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsibL.png)

I tried to run the app to my iPhone (IOS 15.4.1), the build is done successfully , but it comes up with (Unable to install "Runner").

[Unable to install Runner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLp2s.png)

It shows that the Executable file is not specified, but I checked that the Executable file parameter is determine correctly .

[Executable file parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsDm7.png)

Any solutions?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you ever run the app on your iPhone ? Is this your first app with flutter ?

Comment: This is not my first flutter app. I already run another app on my iPhone before and deployed it to app store successfully.